# how to place legend at multiple positions in r

Tags: r, plot, legend

I have made a barplot using `R` with legends. But legends are almost covering half width. There are total 10 legend in plot. I think I should place 5 legends at topright and 5 at top left. How can I place legends at multiple positions ?

Comment: Just as a side remark, if you create a pdf out of your plot, you likely won't have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With base plot, you can have two different legend calls for "topright" and "topleft".

```
x <- 1:10
my_colors <- 1:10
barplot(x,ylim=c(1,15),col=my_colors)
legend("topleft",legend=x[1:5],col=my_colors[1:5],lty=1)
legend("topright",legend=x[6:10],col=my_colors[6:10],lty=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this was I expecting